# VBA: Best Way of Setting Cell Formatting to Default

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I've created a function for setting a cell or cells to default formatting (i.e. what all cells look like in a new worksheet). Here's my function,

```
Public Function setDefaultCellFormat(ByVal worksheetName As String, ByVal target As Range)
    Dim neutralTintAndShade As Single: neutralTintAndShade = 0

    With Worksheets(worksheetName).target.Font
        .color = xlWhite
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Subscript = False
        .Superscript = False
    End With

    With Worksheets(worksheetName).target.Borders
        .color = vbWhite
        .LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorNone
        .TintAndShade = neutralTintAndShade
        .Weight = 1
    End With

    With Worksheets(worksheetName).target.Interior
        .color = vbWhite
        .Gradient = xlGradientNone
        .InvertIfNegative = False
        .Pattern = xlPatternNone
        .PatternColor = xlWhite
        .PatternThemeColor = xlWhite
        .PatternTintAndSage = neutralTintAndShade
        .ThemeColor = xlWhite
        .TintAndShade = neutralTintAndShade
    End With
End Function
```

Obviously, my function is quite lengthy. Hence, I was wondering if it's possible to refactor it in a simpler way. E.g. can the Font, Borders, and Interior objects be reset as if it was from a new worksheet?

Comment: Can't you just clear all formatting, i.e. [`Range.ClearFormats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearformats)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Range.ClearFormats** - this will clear the formatting of the object (e.g. font, borders, interior colour).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearformats